# OpenCV Mat to Qt QString

Tags: qt, opencv, qstring, opencv-mat

I'm using opencv in a Qt app. I've seen some generic c++ ways of printing out the values of a Mat and have done so with

```
cout << "myMat = "<< endl << " "  << myMat << endl << endl;
```

Ideally I could have a QString with the contents of this Mat. Is there a neat way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ostringstream` and its method `str()` to get string which you can pass as parameter to `QString` constructor.

```
    cv::Mat M(2,2, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0,0,255));
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << "M = " << endl << " " << M << endl;
    QString matContent(oss.str()); // QT3
    QString matContent2(oss.str().c_str()); // QT4/5 (const char*) constructor
```

Comment: This resulted in  `error: conversion from ‘std::basic_ostringstream<char>::__string_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to non-scalar type ‘QString’ requested`              but it's got me damn close so thank you. I'll put my solution up as the answer.